# Set Layout width percentage of the total screen width

Tags: java, android

Is there's way to set Button width 50% of the total screen size (from java code).
I have found a few answers but i would like to change Button size with java code instead of XML.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out..

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = yourButton.getLayoutParams();
params.width = metrics.widthPixels;

    try {
        double ratio = 0.5;
        params.height = Double.valueOf(ratio * height).intValue();
        yourButton.setLayoutParams(params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to achieve this, you could try like below:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params= yourBtn.getLayoutParams();
params.width= width * 1/2;
yourBtn.setLayoutParams(params);
yourBtn.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's so simple just do.

```
button.getLayoutParams().width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/2;
```

Answer (score 1):

**I hope it Helps**

> possible with of `Guideline constraint`

## Guideline

> Utility class representing a Guideline helper object for
>   ConstraintLayout. Helper objects are not displayed on device (they are
>   marked as View.GONE) and are only used for layout purposes. They only
>   work within a ConstraintLayout.
>
> A Guideline can be either horizontal or vertical:
>
> Vertical Guidelines have a width of zero and the height of their
>   ConstraintLayout parent Horizontal Guidelines have a height of zero
>   and the width of their ConstraintLayout parent Positioning a Guideline
>   is possible in three different ways:
>
> specifying a fixed distance from the left or the top of a layout
>   `(layout_constraintGuide_begin)` specifying a fixed distance from the
>   right or the bottom of a layout `(layout_constraintGuide_end)`
>   specifying a percentage of the width or the height of a layout
>   `(layout_constraintGuide_percent)` Widgets can then be constrained to
>   a Guideline, allowing multiple widgets to be positioned easily from
>   one Guideline, or allowing reactive layout behavior by using percent
>   positioning.
>
> See the list of attributes in ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams to set a
>   Guideline in XML, as well as the corresponding
>   `ConstraintSet.setGuidelineBegin(int, int),
>   ConstraintSet.setGuidelineEnd(int, int) and
>   ConstraintSet.setGuidelinePercent(int, float) functions in
>   ConstraintSet.`

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50" />
```

**

> Example

**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="104dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.80" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Example with Layout height 50% of screen

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50" />
```

> ## 2nd Way

**## getDefaultDisplay ()**

> public abstract Display getDefaultDisplay () Returns the Display upon
>   which this WindowManager instance will create new windows.
>
> Despite the name of this method, the display that is returned is not
>   necessarily the primary display of the system (see
>   Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY). The returned display could instead be a
>   secondary display that this window manager instance is managing. Think
>   of it as the display that this WindowManager instance uses by default.
>
> To create windows on a different display, you need to obtain a
>   WindowManager for that Display. (See the WindowManager class
>   documentation for more information.)

```
Display mDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
final int width  = mDisplay.getWidth();
final int height = mDisplay.getHeight();

// now simple height/2  use it as u want
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this perhaps? Not sure if it will work exactly as you want it but thats the general idea of it

```
Configuration configuration = getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration();
        int screenWidthDp = configuration.screenWidthDp;
        final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int pixels = (int) (screenWidthDp * scale);
button1.setWidth(pixels*0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
yourbutton.setLayoutParams(params);`

```
Resources r = mContext.getResources();
int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
    yourdpmeasure, 
    r.getDisplayMetrics());
```